# How can I mitigate encoding error that happens irregularly while scraping data?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, encoding, edgar

I was scraping SEC EDGAR data by running 'MDA Extractor.py' in this link.
https://github.com/rflugum/10K-MDA-Section

As this program was made in Python2, I changed some expressions (e.g., print -> print(), xrange -> range), and added useragent to avoid blocking.

Meanwhile, when it reads the link number '39126' (https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/30302/0000030302-02-000003.txt),

The following error was generated:

```
['39126', 'edgar/data/30302/0000030302-02-000003.txt']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MDAExtractor.py", line 261, in (module) headerclean(temp, temp1) 
File "MDAExtractor.py", line 112, in headerclean **for** x, line in enumerate(hand):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.**errors**, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 467: invalid start byte
```

I was confused because it was running well before reading the link 39126. And I tried to add "encoding = 'utf-16'" to some potential places, but it generated errors. I wonder how can I handle this and make a more broadly applicable code.

The lines related to the error are as follows:

```
#################################################################################
#This is the file that records the number of sections for each respective filing.
#################################################################################
LOG=os.path.join(filepath,"DOWNLOADLOG.txt")
with open(LOG,'w') as f:
    f.write("Filer\tSECTIONS\n")
    f.close()

######## Download the filing ############
headers = {'User-Agent': 'A B@C.D'}

with open(download, 'r') as txtfile:
    reader = csv.reader(txtfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
        FileNUM=line[0].strip()
        Filer=os.path.join(filepath, "MDA_processed/"+str(line[0].strip())+".txt")
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/' + line[1].strip()
        with open(temp, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get('%s' % url, headers = headers).content)
        f.close()
        
##### Obtain Header Information on Filing ######################        
        
        parse(temp, Filer)
        headerclean(temp, temp1)   ####### LINE 261 !!!!!!!#####
        
##### ASCII Section ######################        
    
        with open(temp,'r') as f:
            str1=f.read()
            output=str1
            locations_xbrlbig=xbrl_clean("<type>zip", "</document>", output)
            locations_xbrlbig.append(len(output))
            
            if locations_xbrlbig!=[]:
                str1=""
                if len(locations_xbrlbig)%2==0:
                    for i in range(0,len(locations_xbrlbig),2):
                        str1=str1+output[locations_xbrlbig[i]:locations_xbrlbig[i+1]]

        f.close
        output=str1
        locations_xbrlbig=xbrl_clean("<type>graphic", "</document>", output)
        locations_xbrlbig.append(len(output))
        
        if locations_xbrlbig!=[0]:
            str1=""
            if len(locations_xbrlbig)%2==0:
                for i in range(0,len(locations_xbrlbig),2):
                    str1=str1+output[locations_xbrlbig[i]:locations_xbrlbig[i+1]]
        
        output=str1
        locations_xbrlbig=xbrl_clean("<type>excel", "</document>", output)
        locations_xbrlbig.append(len(output))
        
        if locations_xbrlbig!=[0]:
            str1=""
            if len(locations_xbrlbig)%2==0:
                for i in range(0,len(locations_xbrlbig),2):
                    str1=str1+output[locations_xbrlbig[i]:locations_xbrlbig[i+1]]
                    
        output=str1
        locations_xbrlbig=xbrl_clean("<type>pdf", "</document>", output)
        locations_xbrlbig.append(len(output))
        
        if locations_xbrlbig!=[0]:
            str1=""
            if len(locations_xbrlbig)%2==0:
                for i in range(0,len(locations_xbrlbig),2):
                    str1=str1+output[locations_xbrlbig[i]:locations_xbrlbig[i+1]]
        
        output=str1
        locations_xbrlbig=xbrl_clean("<type>xml", "</document>", output)
        locations_xbrlbig.append(len(output))
        
        if locations_xbrlbig!=[0]:
            str1=""
            if len(locations_xbrlbig)%2==0:
                for i in range(0,len(locations_xbrlbig),2):
                    str1=str1+output[locations_xbrlbig[i]:locations_xbrlbig[i+1]]

        output=str1
        locations_xbrlbig=xbrl_clean("<type>ex", "</document>", output)
        locations_xbrlbig.append(len(output))
        
        if locations_xbrlbig!=[0]:
            str1=""
            if len(locations_xbrlbig)%2==0:
                for i in range(0,len(locations_xbrlbig),2):
                    str1=str1+output[locations_xbrlbig[i]:locations_xbrlbig[i+1]]
```

```
###########################  DELETE HEADER INFORMATION  #######################################

def headerclean(temp, temp1):
    mark0=0
    strings1=['</SEC-HEADER>','</IMS-HEADER>']
    hand=open(temp)
    hand.seek(0)
    for x, line in enumerate(hand):
        line=line.strip()
        if any(s in line for s in strings1):
            mark0=x
            break
    hand.seek(0)
    
    newfile=open(temp1,'w')
    for x, line in enumerate(hand):   ###### LINE 112 !!!!!##########
        if x>mark0:
            newfile.write(line)
    hand.close()
    newfile.close()
    
    newfile=open(temp1,'r')
    hand=open(temp,'w')        
    for line in newfile:
        if "END PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE" not in line:
            hand.write(line)                
    hand.close()                
    newfile.close()
```

Comment: in section `######## Download the filing ############` replace `f.write(requests.get('%s' % url, headers = headers).content)` with `f.write(requests.get('%s' % url, headers = headers).text)` also you can remove `f.close()`

Comment: Hi. I followed your comment but it generates 


```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Comment: I fixed all errors I could find and tested it: https://dpaste.com/GMU666367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'user-agent': '`A B@C.D`'}
with open(download, 'r') as txtfile:
    reader = csv.reader(txtfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
        FileNUM = line[0].strip()
        Filer = os.path.join(filepath,"MDA_processed/"+str(line[0].strip()) + ".txt")
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/' + line[1].strip()
        response = requests.get('%s' % url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')  
        filing_document = soup.body.text.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')
        #print(filing_document)
  
        with open(temp, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(filing_document)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).